# Escopo de service-worker?

Tags: javascript, pwa, service-worker, scope

Estou trabalhando em um PWA e gostaria de saber se o escopo ou o diretório onde se encontra o arquivo do service-worker pode interferir, como por exemplo, nas notificações push.

Um arquivo que se encontra dentro de `/statics/sw.js` funcionará da mesma forma que um que está na raiz do projeto??

Comment: Quando você registrar o SW voce pode definir o scopo `navigator.serviceWorker.register('/statics/sw.js', {scope: '/'})`

Comment: Tentei isso, e retornou um erro dizendo que estava acima do escopo permitido e pedia para mover o arquivo para a pasta `/statics` e definir o escopo para `/statics` também

Comment: Esse é o erro que retorno quando eu defino o escopo:
`The path of the provided scope ('/') is not under the max scope allowed ('/statics/'). Adjust the scope, move the Service Worker script, or use the Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP header to allow the scope.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Um arquivo que se encontra dentro de /statics/sw.js funcionará da mesma forma que um que está na raiz do projeto??

**Não funcionará**, ele apenas terá acesso aos eventos fetch que iniciam com `/statics`

Referencia:https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/?hl=pt-br

> Um ponto sutil do método register() é a localização do arquivo do service worker. Neste caso, você notará que o arquivo do service worker está na raiz do domínio. Isso significa que o escopo do service worker será a origem completa. Em outras palavras, este service worker receberá eventos fetch para tudo nesse domínio. Se registrarmos o arquivo do service worker em /example/sw.js, ele verá apenas os eventos fetch das páginas com URL iniciando com /example/ (ou seja, /example/page1/, /example/page2/).

Comment: E como eu faria para declarar um service-worker que vai gerenciar as notificações push do meu PWA?? Colocar 2 service-workers na raiz do projeto, acredito eu, que dá conflito... Poderia me fornecer algum exemplo de como fazer?? Agradeço muito a sua ajuda.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/?hl=pt-br

Comment: Resolvi o problema de uma forma não convencional, quando eu dava o comando para buildar o projeto, o Quasar Framework, que é o que estou usando gerava o service-worker sozinho e minificado.
Fui nas configurações de build e coloquei para não minificar e depois de 'buildado' o projeto adicionei os event listeners que eu precisava naquele service-worker gerado e funcionou como o esperado.

Comment: Agradeço imensamente a sua ajuda e a sua disposição @David Schrammel...